# MP4 files playing failed with php

Tags: php, html, mp4

I am developing html5 video. It seems that when I try to embed the video with the direct url, the video can always be played successfully. However, when I tried to use php to get content from url in video/mp4 content, it cannot be played. How can I make sure that I can make the video being played successfully even though I use php? (The video would be successfully played with php if I set content type to be application/octet-stream and content disposition to be attachment)Please do not teach me the method of fopen since I need to encrypt the mp4 so the source content must be in string format.

```
$zipc="decrypted_string";
header("Content-type: video/mp4");
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:'.(strlen($zipc)));
header("Content-Range: bytes 0-".(strlen($zipc)-1)."/".strlen($zipc));
echo $zipc;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the php function `ob_end_clean()` and all things work.